# define a new function for keyboard-quit and highlight clearup

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am pretty new to elisp, and i was trying to define a function to set highlight behavior while searching. The goal is: after `i-search`, I want to be able to clear the highlight with `C-g`, but I want the highlight to remain if I press enter.

So i defined a function in my `init.el` as:

```
(defun keyboard-quit-cleanup ()
  "clean up highligh after keyboard quit"
  (keyboard-quit)
  (lazy-highlight-cleanup))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-g") '(keyboard-quit-cleanup))
```

how-ever, it doesn't work. What's wrong here?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lots of things, I'm afraid :)

1. Your `global-set-key` is broken:

   ```
   (global-set-key (kbd "C-g") 'keyboard-quit-cleanup)
   ```

   not:

   ```
   (global-set-key (kbd "C-g") '(keyboard-quit-cleanup))
   ```

   (where did you see that??)
2. Your custom function is not an interactive command, so you *cannot* bind it to a key. It needs to be:

   ```
   (defun keyboard-quit-cleanup ()
     "Clean up highlights after keyboard quit."
     (interactive)
     ...)
   ```
3. You probably want to use the `FORCE` argument to `lazy-highlight-cleanup`
4. You're binding the wrong thing.

   <kbd>C-g</kbd> is bound to `isearch-abort` in the `isearch-mode-map` keymap.

   (edit: and as per tripleee's comment, messing with the *global* binding is surely a bad idea. There's definitely some special behaviour associated with it, and you don't want to risk breaking it.)
5. As you're looking to add an additional behaviour to a standard behaviour, you probably want to use a hook (by preference) or some advice. In this case there's a convenient hook we can use.

   See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `isearch-mode-end-hook` <kbd>RET</kbd>

   ```el
   (add-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook 'my-isearch-end)
   (defun my-isearch-end ()
     "Custom behaviours for `isearch-mode-end-hook'."
     (when isearch-mode-end-hook-quit
       (lazy-highlight-cleanup t)))
   ```

(I assume you have `lazy-highlight-cleanup` set to `nil` normally, as otherwise the clean-up happens by default.)

Comment: Perhaps emphasize that rebinding C-g globally is an extremely bad idea.