# How to disable sticky highlight for repeat isearch forward / backward

Tags: emacs

Without hacking the source or creating my own isearch-repeat... function, is it possible to disable the default sticky highlight for `isearch-repeat-forward` and `isearch-repeat-backward`?

I'm using the latest developer build of Emacs Trunk --with-ns.

---

Here are some ideas (a work in progress), but they do not resolve the issue -- `isearch-mode-end-hook` does not seem to be linked to `isearch-repeat-forward` and `isearch-repeat-backward`.  It would be nice if any keyboard input (escape and/or arrow keys) could momentarily be linked to `lawlist-lazy-highlight-cleanup` when exiting `isearch-repeat`.

```
(add-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook 'my-isearch-end)
(defun my-isearch-end ()
  "Custom behaviors for `isearch-mode-end-hook'."
  (when isearch-mode-end-hook-quit
    (lawlist-lazy-highlight-cleanup t)))

(defun lawlist-lazy-highlight-cleanup (&optional force)
  "Stop lazy highlighting and remove extra highlighting from current buffer.
FORCE non-nil means do it whether or not `lazy-highlight-cleanup'
is nil.  This function is called when exiting an incremental search if
`lazy-highlight-cleanup' is non-nil."
  (interactive '(t))
  (if (or force lazy-highlight-cleanup)
      (while isearch-lazy-highlight-overlays
        (delete-overlay (car isearch-lazy-highlight-overlays))
        (setq isearch-lazy-highlight-overlays
              (cdr isearch-lazy-highlight-overlays))))
  (when isearch-lazy-highlight-timer
    (cancel-timer isearch-lazy-highlight-timer)
    (setq isearch-lazy-highlight-timer nil))
(lawlist-isearch-dehighlight))

(defun lawlist-isearch-dehighlight ()
(interactive)
  (when isearch-overlay
    (delete-overlay isearch-overlay)))

(defun lawlist-isearch-repeat-forward ()
  "Repeat incremental search forwards."
  (interactive)
  (isearch-repeat 'forward)
;; need to add something that says sit-for any keyboard input before cleanup occurs.
;; (read-event) ;; read-char-exclusive | read-char | read-event
(sit-for 60)
(lawlist-lazy-highlight-cleanup))

(defun lawlist-isearch-repeat-backward ()
  "Repeat incremental search backwards."
  (interactive)
  (isearch-repeat 'backward)
;; need to add something that says sit-for any keyboard input before cleanup occurs.
;; (read-event) ;; read-char-exclusive | read-char | read-event
(sit-for 60)
(lawlist-lazy-highlight-cleanup))
```

Comment: The default behavior for `isearch-forward` and `isearch-backward` is to find the result and highlight it -- pressing an arrow key thereafter removes the highlight from the word.  The default behavior for `isearch-repeat-forward` and `isearch-repeat-backward` is to find the result and highlight it persistently -- pressing an arrow key  does `not` remove the highlight from the word.  I would like `isearch-repeat-forward` and `isearch-repeat-backward` to disengage the highlight from the word as soon as I use an arrow key, instead of the word remaining highlighted.

Comment: `isearch-repeat-forward` and `isearch-repeat-backward` are behaving as if the functions are hard-coded with all of the following:  `(setq lazy-highlight-cleanup nil)` and `(setq lazy-highlight-max-at-a-time nil)` and `(setq lazy-highlight-initial-delay 0)`.  However, I am not using any of those settings -- this is just an example to describe the `sticky` persistent highlight behavior that occurs with `isearch-repeat-forward` and `isearch-repeat-backward`.  The aforementioned code, if used, would cause `isearch-forward` and `isearch-backward` to become sticky also -- i.e., persistent highight.

Comment: This thread contains an idea for using a custom `isearch-mode-end-hook`, but it doesn't work for my particular issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804131/define-a-new-function-for-keyboard-quit-and-highlight-clearup   Also, `lazy-highlight-cleanup` doesn't completely remove all the highlighting caused by `isearch-repeat` -- it needs an additional `isearch-dehighlight`.  If I combine the two functions, then the highlighting can be removed -- but it is not linked to an arrow key and I would only want the arrow keys linked when exiting a search.

Comment: I just about have it . . . (sit-for 60) keeps it highlighted for a minute, or I can press any key and cleanup occurs.  If I want to repeat the search immediately I can do that also.  Read-event, read-char and read-char-exclusive waste a keyboard stroke, so the sit-for appears to be a better option.

Comment: Why are you calling `isearch-repeat-forward` explicitly? As I understand your question, `isearch-forward` does what you want already, why worry about `isearch-repeat-forward`? I'm confused as to what your ultimate objective is here.

Comment: Tyler: that part is automatic. Compare: `C-k C-s` vs `C-s C-h k C-s`

Comment: lawlist: is this a new behaviour (or a bug) in trunk? In 24.3 (and in all prior versions I can recall since the lazy highlighting was introduced) there is no difference in the default lazy highlight cleanup behaviour between the initial isearch and subsequent repeats. Do you see this with `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: Oh, now I see. Tyler was right, and you *are* calling this explicitly (or at least that would explain the behaviour you have described). That really hadn't occurred to me.

Comment: I frequently have a term that appears several times within a given document, and I have to jump to the next or prior occurrence of the term until I find the one I'm looking for.  If I only use the initial search forward or backward, I would need to re-enter the search term again into the mini-buffer -- the repeat search makes it so that I don't have to retype the term and I can keep jumping backwards or forwards until I reach the desired location.  I don't know how long this behavior has been present in Emacs since I only started using it a few months ago, and am still on a learning swerve. :)

Comment: Yes, 24.3.50 (9.0) Emacs Trunk (--with-ns) [Graphical User Interface, on an OSX box] behaves like this out-of-the box with a blank / empty .emacs file -- i.e., isearch-repeat. . . has a sticky highlight.

Comment: `C-s C-s` repeats the previous forward search, and `C-r C-r` repeats the last backward search. No need to re-enter the search term.

Comment: I just did a C-h k on C-s C-s and C-r C-r -- C-s C-s uses `isearch-repeat-forward`; and, C-r C-r uses `isearch-repeat-backward`.

Comment: Yes it does. `isearch-repeat` is called from `isearch-forward` and `isearch-backward`. It is not normally called on it's own. When called via `C-s C-s`, the highlighting is not sticky - it disappears as soon as you end the search. Is this not what you're after? As I understand your question, the problem with sticky highlighting only occurs when you call `isearch-repeat` functions explicitly, not when they are called automatically from within the `isearch` functions.

Comment: I just verified your observation -- you are correct as to the behavior of repeat not defaulting to sticky highlight under that circumstance.  When building Emacs Trunk `--with-ns`, the file `. . ./lisp/term/ns-win.el` is incorporated.  At line 119:  `(define-key global-map [?\s-d] 'isearch-repeat-backward)`.  At line 122:  `(define-key global-map [?\s-g] 'isearch-repeat-forward)`.  Based upon your observation, we now have two-ways to resolve the issue -- i.e., use `C-s C-s` and `C-r C-r`, or use something similar to the code in my sample answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the source code of `isearch.el` as a guide, the following OSX additional key assignments eliminate the problem with sticky highlight as outlined in the question above.

```
(define-key global-map [?\s-f] 'isearch-forward)
(define-key esc-map [?\s-f] 'isearch-forward-regexp)
(define-key minibuffer-local-isearch-map [?\s-f] 'isearch-forward-exit-minibuffer)
(define-key isearch-mode-map [?\s-f] 'isearch-repeat-forward)

(define-key global-map [?\s-F] 'isearch-backward)
(define-key esc-map [?\s-F] 'isearch-backward-regexp)
(define-key minibuffer-local-isearch-map [?\s-F] 'isearch-reverse-exit-minibuffer)
(define-key isearch-mode-map [?\s-F] 'isearch-repeat-backward)
```

Answer (score 1):

While this does not anwswer your question, it may do the thing you ultimately want to solve:

```
(define-key isearch-mode-map [(control up)]   'isearch-ring-retreat)
(define-key isearch-mode-map [(control down)] 'isearch-ring-advance)
```

After you type C-S, you may use C-up and C-down to move through search history.  So C-S C-up will do what you want: repeat the last search without leaving "sticky" overlays.

See also search-ring-update, to further custom this if you like.

Comment: `isearch-ring-advance` and `isearch-ring-retreat` are already bound to keys in the `isearch-mode-map`: `M-n` and `M-p`